# Use what instead of Deprecated GTK CList?

Tags: gtk, gtk2, clist

I'm just learning GTK (I'm using C) and I see from https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkCList.html#GtkCList-struct that "GtkCList is deprecated and should not be used in newly-written code", but I can't seem to find what should be used instead. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of that same page, you have a "description" section where you may read:

> [GtkCList has been deprecated since GTK+ 2.0 and should not be used in
> newly written code. Use GtkTreeView instead.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkCList.html#GtkCList.description)

There's a navigation bar on top which easily allows you to access specific sections of the documentation of the class.